# how to let files in pycharm see different ones?

Tags: python, pycharm, parent-child

Suppose we have a `directory`: `main` that includes:

- `directory_1`

  - `file_1.py`
- `directory_2`

  - `file_2.py`

If the main `code` is inside `file_1.py`, how can I `import` `file_2.py`?

If it helps, I am using `pycharm`.

Comment: You should have __init__.py file which can be empty in your directories and then import them like "import directory_2.file2"

Comment: Useful, you might want to drop it in answers so i can accept it.

Comment: Formatted the directory structure properly and made the question very clear and obvious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Alex as per your suggestion I am posting this as an answer.

Adding a `__init__.py` (can be empty) is the way python understand the package.So you can add the file in your directory and then import the module

```
from directory_2 import file2
```

Answer (score 0):

just simply add `__init__.py` to each directory (dir_1 and dir_2). 
Note that you don't need to write anything to 2 of `__init__.py`, it's fine to just leave it blank.